# Map annotation clicks not triggering and annotation bars not showing

Tags: ios, swift, mapkit

I am trying to get individual event details to instantiate them in a new view controller but I can't seem to figure how I'm going wrong on just printing the name of the event when I tap the annotations that appear on the map, any help is appreciated

**MapViewController**:

```
class MapViewController: UIViewController {
    var userRides: [UserRides] = []

    @IBOutlet weak
    var HostButton: UIButton!
        @IBOutlet weak
    var ViewButton: UIButton!
        @IBOutlet weak
    var mapView: MKMapView!
        override func viewDidLoad() {
            super.viewDidLoad()
            getRides()
            NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(refreshRides), name: Notification.Name("refresh"), object: nil)
        }
    @objc func refreshRides(notification: NSNotification) {
        getRides()
    }
    func getRides() {
        let db = Firestore.firestore()
        db.collection("Events").getDocuments() {
            (snapshot, err) in
            if let err = err {
                print("Error getting documents: \(err)")
            } else {
                let documents = snapshot!.documents
                try !documents.forEach {
                    document in
                        let userRides: UserRides =
                            try document.decoded()
                    print(userRides.rideName)
                    self.userRides.append(userRides)
                }
                for ride in 0.. < self.userRides.count {
                    let mapPins = EventAnno()
                    let rides = self.userRides[ride]
                    mapPins.title = rides.rideName
                    mapPins.myRide = rides
                    let coordinate = CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: rides.rideYCordinate, longitude: rides.rideXCordinate)
                    mapPins.coordinate = coordinate
                    self.mapView.addAnnotation(mapPins)
                    print(self.userRides.count)
                }
            }
        }
    }
    func mapView(_ mapView: MKMapView, didSelect view: MKAnnotationView) {
        if let eventAnnotation = view.annotation as ? EventAnno {
            let theEvent = eventAnnotation.myRide
            print(theEvent ? .rideName ? ? "ride name")
        }
    }
}

class EventAnno: MKPointAnnotation {
    var myRide: UserRides ?
}
```

**UserRides**:

```
struct UserRides: Decodable{
    let rideDate : String
    let rideLeader : String
    let rideLeaderUID : String
    let rideLocation : String
    let rideName : String
    let rideType: String
    let rideXCordinate : Double
    let rideYCordinate : Double
}
```

------------------------------ EDIT ------------------------------

below is my second attempt on the **MapViewController** to get at it from a different angle with still no results.

```
class MapViewController: UIViewController{
    var userRides:[UserRides] = []

    @IBOutlet weak var HostButton: UIButton!
    @IBOutlet weak var ViewButton: UIButton!
    @IBOutlet weak var mapView: MKMapView!
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        getRides()
        NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(refreshRides), name: Notification.Name("refresh"), object: nil)
        mapView.delegate = self
    }
    @objc func refreshRides (notification: NSNotification){
        getRides()
    }
    func getRides(){
             let db = Firestore.firestore()
             db.collection("Events").getDocuments() { (snapshot, err) in
             if let err = err {
                 print("Error getting documents: \(err)")
             } else {
                 let documents = snapshot!.documents
                 try! documents.forEach{document in
                     let userRides: UserRides = try document.decoded()
                      print(userRides.rideName)
                     self.userRides.append(userRides)
                 }
              for ride in 0..<self.userRides.count {
                  let mapPins = MKPointAnnotation()
                  let rides = self.userRides[ride]
                  mapPins.title = rides.rideName
                  let coordinate = CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: rides.rideYCordinate, longitude: rides.rideXCordinate)
                  mapPins.coordinate = coordinate
                  self.mapView.addAnnotation(mapPins)
                  print(self.userRides.count)
              }
          }
      }
   }
}

extension MapViewController: MKMapViewDelegate {
    func annotateMap() {
        var parent: MapViewController func mapView(_ mapView: MKMapView, viewFor annotation: MKAnnotation) -> MKAnnotationView? {
            let identifier="Placemark" var annotationView=mapView.dequeueReusableAnnotationView(withIdentifier: identifier) if annotationView==nil {
                annotationView=MKPinAnnotationView(annotation: annotation, reuseIdentifier: identifier) annotationView?.canShowCallout=true annotationView?.rightCalloutAccessoryView=UIButton(type: .detailDisclosure)
            }
            else {
                annotationView?.annotation=annotation
            }
            return annotationView
        }
        func mapView(_ mapView: MKMapView, didSelect view: MKAnnotationView) {
            print("\(String(describing: view.annotation?.title))")
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is working code to get pin data from firebase, my issue was I was referencing the incorrect map on the weakVar, check your variables people!

```
import UIKit
import MapKit
import Firebase
import FirebaseAuth

class MapViewController: UIViewController{
    var userRides:[UserRides] = []

    @IBOutlet weak var HostButton: UIButton!
    @IBOutlet weak var ViewButton: UIButton!
    @IBOutlet weak var mapView: MKMapView!
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        getRides()
        NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(refreshRides), name: Notification.Name("refresh"), object: nil)
        mapView.delegate = self
    }
    @objc func refreshRides (notification: NSNotification){
        getRides()
    }
    func getRides(){
             let db = Firestore.firestore()
             db.collection("Events").getDocuments() { (snapshot, err) in
             if let err = err {
                 print("Error getting documents: \(err)")
             } else {
                 let documents = snapshot!.documents
                 try! documents.forEach{document in
                     let userRides: UserRides = try document.decoded()
                      print(userRides.rideName)
                      self.userRides.append(userRides)
                 }
                for ride in 0..<self.userRides.count {
                    let mapPins = MKPointAnnotation()
                    let rides = self.userRides[ride]
                    mapPins.title = rides.rideName
                    let coordinate = CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: rides.rideYCordinate, longitude: rides.rideXCordinate)
                    mapPins.coordinate = coordinate
                    self.mapView.addAnnotation(mapPins)
                }
            }
      }
   }
}
extension MapViewController: MKMapViewDelegate{
    func mapView(_ mapView: MKMapView,
                 viewFor annotation: MKAnnotation) -> MKAnnotationView? {

        if annotation is MKUserLocation {
            //return nil so map view draws "blue dot" for standard user location
            return nil
        }
        let reuseId = "pin"
        var pinView = mapView.dequeueReusableAnnotationView(withIdentifier: reuseId) as? MKPinAnnotationView
        if pinView == nil {
            pinView = MKPinAnnotationView(annotation: annotation, reuseIdentifier: reuseId)
            pinView!.canShowCallout = true
            pinView!.animatesDrop = true
            pinView!.pinTintColor = .purple
            pinView!.rightCalloutAccessoryView = UIButton(type: .detailDisclosure)
        }
        else {
            pinView!.annotation = annotation
        }
        return pinView
    }
}
```